# Filters/Bulk Actions return wrong URL in admin dashboard

Tags: filters, urls, core

The site that has this bug lives in a subdirectory called /blog/.

In the admin dashboard, whenever the user selects a dropdown (bulk actions/all dates/all categories/etc) , it leads to siteurl.com/wp-admin/edit.php?(rest of url here) instead of siteurl.com/blog/wp-admin/edit.php?(rest of url here)

I was wondering where in the WP Core I could I change the returning URL to make it return siteurl.com/blog/wp-admin/edit.php?(rest of url here)
?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the values of your WordPress and Site URLs (on the Options > General page)?